# How can I subscribe to iframe location changes in an angular app?

Tags: angular, iframe

I have a component with an iframe element. I set the src attribute to the original url, and the user can navigate from there. I want to subscribe to new locations that the user navigates to, assuming they are on the same domain. In non-angular solutions they describe putting an onload event on the iframe, but putting a (load) event on the iframe in angular seems to be fired only once upon initialization, not every time there is a navigation event inside the iframe as I want. I made a very ugly, hacky solution:

```js
    Observable
      .interval(200)
      .map(x => this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.location.pathname)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(url => {
        console.log(url);
      });
```

But this seems suboptimal to say the least. Is there a better solution that doesn't involve polling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did not need to do this, because the code in my iframe knows when the url changes, and I have control over it. Therefore, on url change events I can postMessage to the iframe parent. So this is way better than polling, it is genuinely real time.